# Abstract class and its subclasses

Tags: java, vector, abstract

I have an abstract class `Question`, and a bunch of its subclasses: `EssayQuestion`, `TrueFalseQuestion`, and so on. Each of them have their own (and sometimes unique) variable and methods. A survey is a combination of different kinds of question, so to create and save it I use `Vector<Question>`.

The trouble starts when I try to "unpack" such a vector, each item is treated simply as an instance of `Question`, and doesn't let me use the methods that each individual subclass has.

For example, I'd create one true/false question and add it to my vector

```
    TFQuestion first = new TFQuestion("some text");
    Vector<Question> v = new Vector<Question>();
    v.add(0, first);
```

Say, `TFQuestion` has `getPrompt()` method, but abstract class `Question` does not.

`v.get(0).getPrompt()`
does not exist. However `v.get(0).getClass()` returns that it's an instance of `TFQuestion`.

Comment: You can cast to the desired type in order to invoke the method of that type.

Comment: And what is your question? Btw: why isn't `getPrompt()` an abstract method in `Question`? It doesn't look like something special that only `TrueFalseQuestion` could implement.

Comment: because it's **upcasting** here

Comment: What do you want to do with the questions when you retrieve them from the vector? Do you want to do X if you find an `EssayQuestion` and Y if you find a `TrueFalseQuestion`? Then create an `if` statement that uses `instanceof` checks. Like `if (q instanceof EssayQuestion) { ((EssayQuestion) q).getPrompt() }`.